# Clicking outside of DropdownMenu does not dismiss the menu, DropdownMenuItem does not receive clicks

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am experimenting DropdownMenu and from the documentation, it should call onDismissRequest when I tap outside:

> onDismissRequest will be called when the menu should close - for example when there is a tap outside the menu, or when the back key is pressed.

Clicking on "back" can successfully dismiss the menu.

Another weird thing is that clicking on an DropdownMenuItem does not close the menu, either since it cannot receive any clicking.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
                SampleScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SampleScreen() {
    Scaffold(bottomBar = {MyBottomBar()}) {
        Text("hello world")
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MyBottomBar() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    BottomAppBar {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)) {
                Box {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {expanded = true}
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            Icons.Filled.MoreVert,
                            contentDescription = "more"
                        )
                    }
                    DropdownMenu(
                        expanded = expanded,
                        onDismissRequest = {
                            expanded = false
                        }
                    ) {
                        DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { expanded = false }) {
                            Text("item1")
                        }
                        DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { expanded = false }) {
                            Text("item2")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screen:

[image: sample screen]

Comment: When I run this locally it works fine, there must be something different about your environment. Is there a parent composable which could be intercepting the gesture?

Comment: Updated the code to show that there is no other composables. By the way ,the items are not receiving clicks as well. I run it in a Pixel 3a emulator API 30 Android 11, not on an actual device.

Comment: Compose version 1.0.1

Comment: I ran your exact code on the same emulator and same compose version. The menu still dismisses when I tap outside

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I tried it on an actual pixel 3 device and it works. I then use a Pixel 5 AVD and that works as well. That means it's specific to my Pixel 3a AVD...

Comment: Related Bugs in Issue Tracker:
1. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211841590
2. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211996681
3. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211474319

As discussed in one of the comments in the the first of the three bugs, performing a Wipe Data on your emulator might help.